# ListView contentY changes when rows are moved

Tags: qt, listview, qvector

I have a ListView divided into two sections: favorites and regular items, with a model that inherits `QAbstractItemModel`. The items in the model are sorted so that favorites come before the regular items, and when an item is marked as favorite, it is moved to an appropriate place in the underlying list.

This is the code in the model that does the moving:

```
if (beginMoveRows(QModelIndex(), position, position, QModelIndex(), newPosition)) {
    items.removeAt(position);
    items.insert(newPosition + (newPosition < position ? 0 : -1), item);
    endMoveRows();
}
```

However, each time a move happens, ListView's `contentY` is changed by `-delegate.height` (-120px in this case). The only visible changes are that the scrollbar gets offset and eventually exits the screen.

What's going on and how can I fix it?

**Edit:** I've found that this only happens when the ListView is scrolled completely to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect solution to the problem. Since the only important symptom of this was the fact that the scrollbar was getting offset, I had to find another value for setting the scrollbar's `y` property: `ListView.visibleArea.yPosition`.

This is the entire binding:

```
Binding {
    target: handle
    property: "y"
    value: (flickable.height - handle.height - 25) * flickable.visibleArea.yPosition / (1 - flickable.visibleArea.heightRatio)
}
```

Explanation:

- `flickable.height - handle.height` - this is the portion of the hight over which the top of the scrollbar handle moves
- `25` - my own specific offset, irrelevant to others
- `flickable.visibleArea.yPosition / (1 - flickable.visibleArea.heightRatio)` - this entire number is the percentage from 0% to 100% from scrollbar's highest position to the lowest one (highest `y`)

More about [`ListView.visibleArea.yPosition`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#visibleArea.yPosition-prop).